# Enum response is numeric value and not string

Tags: c#, enums, swagger, middleware, jsonserializer

For all my other enum classes swagger shows the string definition but for one enum class that I use in my 'ExceptionMiddleware' class it shows the numeric value. But in the swagger documentation example it shows the string value..

My enum class :

```
public enum ErrorCode
{
    Undefined = -1,
    None = 0,

    ContractNotFound = 1000
}
```

One of my other enum classes that doesn't have this "problem" :

```
public enum ContractStatus
{
    Undefined = 0,
    Created = 1,
    Valid = 2,
    Invalid = 3
}
```

[image]

A result when the contract is not found :

[image]

I also have to add '[JsonPropertyName("errorCode")]' so the properties start with a lowercase letter. For all my other models this is not needed...

The class :

```
public class ExceptionResponse
{
    [JsonPropertyName("errorCode")]  
    public ErrorCode ErrorCode { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("errorCodeLabel")]
    public string ErrorCodeLabel { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("errorMessage")]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }
}
```

Configuration in 'Program.cs' :

```
o.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());
```

If I remove this all enum's show numeric values instead of string values.

How I build the 'ExceptionResponse' model in my 'ExceptionMiddleware' class :

```
var exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse()
        {
            ErrorCode = ErrorCode.Undefined,
            ErrorCodeLabel = ErrorCode.Undefined.ToString(),
            ErrorMessage = "A random message."
        };
```

And if there is an error :

```
await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(exceptionResponse));
```

Comment: We do not see what you do differently in your other models. Can you post a [mcve]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are manually serializing, you are bypassing the registered middleware that contains your converter. You need to pass an options instance to your serialize call that includes the converter.

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new JsonStringEnumConverter());

await httpContext.Response.WriteAsync(JsonSerializer.Serialize(exceptionResponse, options));
```

It is considered a best practice to cache your serializer options as a static field so that you are not re-creating them each call to Serialize, since this has severe performance repercussions in older versions of `System.Text.Json`.

```
public class ContainingClass
{
    private static readonly JsonSerializerOptions s_options = new()
    {
        Converters =
        {
            new JsonStringEnumConverter()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This did the trick, but what exactly do you mean with making options a static field and where? Create an extension method?

Comment: @user7849697 glad that helped! Apologies for not being clear enough. I've updated my answer for you. You can either create a static field in a shared class or in the class that you are using it in.

Answer (score 0):

You can put this attribute above your Enum declaration. Something like this

```cs
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
public enum ErrorCode
{
    Undefined = -1,
    None = 0,

    ContractNotFound = 1000
}
```

Note that this is for .net core 3 and above. More info for the built-in converter is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonstringenumconverter?view=net-7.0